# QBuffer writes bytes at the start of QByteArray rather than the end

Tags: qt, qbytearray, qbuffer

I have the following code:

```
QByteArray ba; // Declare Byte array
ba.clear();    // Clear it
ba.append(80, 0x00); // Append 80 bytes of 0x00
quint32 Count = 2;   // The number we want to append to the byte array
QBuffer tempBuffer(&ba); // We use temporary buffer to conveniently put integers and floats into byte-array
tempBuffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
Count = qToLittleEndian(Count); // Make sure our number is little Endian
tempBuffer.write((char*)&Count, sizeof(quint32)); // Write the number to byte array
```

When I print to console the content of my byte array:

```
qDebug() << "ba: " << ba.toHex();
```

The console prints:

```
ba:  "0200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

As can be seen above, the `2` which is of type `quint32`, is correctly represented by the little Endian hex value of `0x02000000`, however, it is added at the **start** of the byte array rather than the end. How can I **append** my value to the **end** of the byte array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the buffer in *append* mode instead of *writeonly*:

```
tempBuffer.open(QIODevice::Append);
```